# How to Inject AppDbContext in Wpf core Applications using caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, entity-framework-core, caliburn.micro

I want to add my AppDbContext for every request in my WPFapp.
I'm using caliburn.micro's simple container for dependency injection and I'm wondering How should I register my AppDbContext per request.
Because I should register a pre-constructed instance of it for configure method using `_container.Instance(_db)` or it will throw a null exception when I start the app.
after that if I say `_container.PerRequest<AppDbContext, AppDbContext>()` for example, it will throw an exception and says that "Sequence contains more than one element".
if I don't use `PerRequest<AppDbContext, AppDbContext>()` It will throw a null exception in the class where I Injected AppDbContext in constructor.
How should I register this service?

my Bootstrapper Class:

```
     public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();
        private AppDbContext _db;
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
                     .UseJet(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\AccessDatabase      \TestDatabase1.accdb;")
                 .Options;

            _db = new AppDbContext(options);

            ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<PasswordBox>(
            PasswordBoxHelper.BoundPasswordProperty,
            "Password",
            "PasswordChanged");
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Instance(_container);

            _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
            _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
            _container.PerRequest<DataAccess, DataAccess>();
            _container.Instance(_db);
            _container.PerRequest<AppDbContext, AppDbContext>();


            GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.IsClass)
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterPerRequest(
                    viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));
        }

        protected override async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayRootViewForAsync<ShellViewModel>();
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(instance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you first register it as a singleton if you want to to be resolved "by request"?

Comment: @mm8 because if I don't do that it will throw a null exception for "DbContextOptions" in "AppDbContext" class when It's passing to the base constructor.

Comment: What base constructor?

Comment: @mm8 In AppDbContext class we write :
 `public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }`
And the "DbContextOptions" was null.
The problem started when I couldn't add migrations and I found a solution that i should implement " IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>" and it worked.
in this class it returns `new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options)`
now I deleted the "AppDbContext" constructor and also `_container.Instance(_db)` it's working.

Comment: I don't follow. You are explicitly creating an `AppDbContext` and store it in `_db`, don't you? What's next?